# UWP - Class librairies and PRI file generation

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget

In my UWP solution, I have a **ClassLibrary1** project (with a BlankPage1.xaml) and a **ClassLibrary2** project that references the ClassLibrary1 project (with a BlankPage2.xaml).

I'm doing 2 NuGet packages (one for ClassLibrary1 and another for the ClassLibrary2).

In an UWP app, I added the ClassLibrary2 NuGet package. But, when I compile this app, I get these compilation errors:

```
Error: Could not copy the file "C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\classlibrary2\1.0.0\lib\uap10.0.16299\ClassLibrary1\BlankPage1.xbf" because it was not found.
Error: Could not copy the file "C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\classlibrary2\1.0.0\lib\uap10.0.16299\ClassLibrary1\BlankPage1.xaml" because it was not found.
Error: Could not copy the file "C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\classlibrary2\1.0.0\lib\uap10.0.16299\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.xr.xml" because it was not found.
```

I noticed that the ClassLibrary2.pri file includes these 3 files and it shouldn't because they are included in the ClassLibrary1 NuGet package.

How can I indicate to not include these files in the ClassLibrary2.pri ?

This is a sample project that reproduces the problem : https://github.com/kakone/PriGeneration/

Comment: `ClassLibrary1/*.pri` files get copied over to output folder of ClassLibrary2, just not included in nupkg. Would include `ClassLibrary1/*.pri` files into `ClassLibrary2.nupkg` be an option to you?

Comment: No, it's not really an option, I want to be able to update the ClassLibrary1 NuGet package without updating the ClassLibrary2 package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by copying a custom filtered.layout.resfiles file to the obj folder before the MSBuild target named _GenerateProjectPriFileCore.

I added these lines in my .csproj :

```
<Target Name="CustomPriFileGeneration" BeforeTargets="_GenerateProjectPriFileCore" Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Release' ">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\filtered.layout.resfiles" DestinationFolder="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)" />
</Target>
```

and a filtered.layout.resfiles file in my project :

```
ClassLibrary2\BlankPage2.xaml
ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.xr.xml
```